# "Train to my hometown" vs. "train for my hometown"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which is more correct?

1. *I am leaving early as I have to catch train **to my hometown**.*
2. *I am leaving early as I have to catch train **for my hometown**.*

Any other suggestion to improve is appreciated.

Comment: They mean the same, the first is better, but you need an article before "train".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/for), "for", as a preposition, can mean:

> Having (the place mentioned) as a destination.

And is usually used with the verb "leave", as in:

> I'm leaving for Paris tomorrow.

And after a noun which is going to a specified destination:

> I have to catch the train for Paris.

"[to](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/to)", on the other hand, used when:

> Expressing motion in the direction of (a particular location)

And it is used with verbs like "walk", "go", etc., as in the sentences:

> I'm going to Paris tomorrow.
>   I walked all the way over to Paris.

And after nouns like "visit", "trip":

> A visit to Paris.
>   A short trip to Paris.

Edit: "to" can also be used after vehicles:

> I have to catch the train to Paris.

and it apparently has become more common to use "to", rather than "for" in this case. So, I'd say using "to" here could be better.

Comment: Sorry to pull "native speaker rank" on you, but the most common preposition for this context [has changed significantly over the past century.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+catch+the+train+to%2Cto+catch+the+train+for&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20catch%20the%20train%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20catch%20the%20train%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cto%20catch%20the%20train%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20catch%20the%20train%20for%3B%2Cc0) It's nearly always *...catch **the** train **to** [destination]* today.

Comment: Ah, I guess you're right. I edited my answer now. Thanks

Comment: Downvote (which I accept was a bit harsh) reversed following your edit! :) On reflection, it's probably a good thing that this particular example might help some learners to recognize that preposition use in English is sometimes flexible and/or can change significantly over time (and thus the "correct" preposition for any given context isn't always as clear-cut as they might otherwise assume).

Comment: Thank you so much :D

Comment: In context, _I have to catch the train for Paris_ would imply to me that you weren't going to Paris, but somewhere that the train called at on the way to Paris. So the destination of the train was Paris, but not your destination. Saying that probably assumes the hearer knows where you are actually going. Also, _I have to catch the Paris train_ is a more likely way to say it.

Comment: @ColinFine From Don McLean's ["American Pie,"](https://www.songfacts.com/lyrics/don-mclean/american-pie) *they caught the last train **for** the coast*. And I would argue that the coast *was* their destination. At best, I'd say it's unknown what the *passengers* final destination was. It's not stated.